# Disable "Black screen" on raspbian jessie lite

Tags: raspbian, screen, midori, screen-saver

I set up a raspberry pi to run as a dash/infoboard.

To do this, i used midori and uncutter(to remove the cursor) and start it up from the ~/.bashrc file, like so

```
startx /usr/bin/midori http://google.com
@uncutter -idle 0.1 -root
```

But what every i try, i can't stop the screen from going blank.

Can anyone help me with this?
i been looking at many solutions on the internet, an none worked for me,

The things i tried is.

1. [LXDE Autostart](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5145)
2. [Disbale in rc.local](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8542)
3. [Disable in xinitrc](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/2079)

Thanks for your time

Comment: Putting GUI commands in `.bashrc` is a very bad idea; any instructions you are following which recommend this should be ignored as if they never existed.

Comment: Whats your take then? If you had a clean pi with raspbain jessie lite, how would you make a dashboard?

Comment: You should look up what `.bashrc` is for and consider why using that this way is an idea spread by -- no exaggeration, no offence -- *morons*.  Probably a more common term for dash/infoboard is "kiosk" and where I'd start is described here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57565/5538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything i could thing of, i went back and install scrennly insted.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the screen from going blank try adding `consoleblank=0` to the end of the first line of `/boot/cmdline.txt`

[Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=889937&sid=c2b8232b30cda64ed4cdf94361658a30#p889937)

Answer (score 2):

A common console command which works on every Linux instance I worked with is

```
xset s off -dpms
```

The `s off` part means "turn off screensaver", and `-dpms` prevents DPMS standby/suspend modes.

The equivalent configuration can be done via `xorg.conf` using

```
Option "DPMS"        "false"
Option "BlankTime"   "0"
```

Those options should go to `Monitor` and `ServerLayout` sections, respectively.

Comment: Adding the options to the `xorg.conf` helped. Everything else was launching this annoying blank screen after two minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

Running Raspbian Jesse Lite (no X11) on an A+ I too struggled to disable the screen automatically blanking. I suspect that it is related to [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=771161).

From [this forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=122112) I found entering the command line`sudo sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -blank 0 >/dev/tty0"` (or booting with `setterm -blank 0` in .bashrc) worked for me.