# Pi OS - Scheduling screen on/off time

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

Running digital signage software on Pi OS 24/7 to inform people about Covid-19 and such.
In the weekends and at night this is not necessary.

Is there software or a setting where I can schedule a screen off/on time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schedule a cron job which disables the screensaver / energy saving (`xset s off -dpms`) on Monday morning, and another job which re-enables the the screensaver / energy saving (or simply reboots the system) on Friday night.

Or [permanently disable](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/61397/33476) the screensaver/DPMS and manage the HDMI output using `tvservice --off` / `tvservice --preferred`

Comment: The cron job set me on the right path, got it working with:

Monitor off:  30 17 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/vcgencmd display_power 0
Monitor on:  30 07  * * 1-5 /usr/bin/vcgencmd display_power 1