# How do I programmatically set the mouse position at boot time?

Tags: pi-3, mouse

[image]

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi with a display as a kiosk. I do not want to see the menu bar of the GUI. Thanks to 'xdotool and uncultter' I also hid the mouse cursor. However, at boot, the mouse position is at the left, which causes the menu bar to show, which I do not want.

How can I move the mouse at boot so that the menu bar does not show (or otherwise hide the menu bar)?

Comment: Am I the only one who does not understand this question?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using the [DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) at all?  If it is just in the way, you'd be better off running your kiosk app standalone on top of the Xorg server: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57565/5538 -> Then there will be no menu bar to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Install the given package:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils unclutter
```

And modify this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add this in the above file:

```
xserver-command=X -nocursor
```

Alternatively, you can remove all items form the task bar:

```
task bar > right click > remove
```

Good Luck
Thanks

Comment: You need to look over the formatting, use the {} button for code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the package *`sudo apt update && sudo apt install xautomation`* then set up a script to move the mouse curser. Hiding it should really be enough but if you really want to move it carry on.

`xte 'mousemove 0 0' -x:0` should do it, assuming your xdisplay is 0.