# Replace PIXEL with Electron App

Tags: gui, node.js, pixel, raspbian-lite, desktop

Is it possible to only have one full-screen application run without the PIXEL desktop environment on the current Raspbian Stretch Lite? So basically, replace PIXEL with a regular desktop GUI application (made with the Electron framework, in my case). If so, do I need to optimize it somehow or can I just use the code of the desktop application without any changes?

Comment: YES - Most of us don't use PIXEL [PIXEL desktop: now defunct and replaced by Raspbian Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=161246)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to only have one full-screen application run without the PIXEL desktop environment

Yes. There are three or four basic userspace layers (i.e., not including the kernel, which controls the hardware) involved in contemporary GNU/Linux based GUI desktops.

- The Xorg server is the most fundamental and the only one which is required. Although there are ways to do graphics without it, those are unlikely to be used in a "GUI desktop" context.  There are newer alternatives to it (X has been evolving since the early eighties), but it is still predominant and what is used by default on Raspbian.

  X has a variety of responsibilities but all we need to know here is that it is what creates the "windows" (the Xorg server is actually an implementation of the [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System)) used by desktop applications. It also provides for HIDs (human interface devices, usually a keyboard and mouse).

  And that's about it.  If you start Xorg without the next two layers and without running an application inside, all you'll see is a black screen with an X shaped mouse pointer.  There are no menus, taskbars, etc., so the user is in a pretty boring place.  However **this is all GUI applications actually need to run**.  I.e., You can configure X to run a normal app at this point, and that would be a standard approach to [creating a kiosk](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57565/5538), which is a system that runs "one full-screen application".
- The *window manager* elaborates on the X primitives; features like borders, titlebars, smart placement, themes, minimizing, etc. are implemented by the window manager.  If you are running one full screen app, this doesn't serve much of a purpose.  Some WM's can be used without the next layer and may include some of its features.
- The *desktop environment* (e.g. PIXEL) is responsible for stuff like taskbars, menus, icons, managing multiple desktops, etc. and usually include at least a file browser.

You can read more about the last two in [that other answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57565/5538) I already linked.  To these we might add the widget library (Gtk+, Qt) but that is only of interest if you are writing desktop apps.

Also in that answer is a bit about **nodm**, which would be one of the first things you should explore.  This helps deal with the role of the *display manager*, also explained there.